# How to use a JProgressBar in a different Thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jprogressbar

I'm using POI in a function to fill the content of my excel document (it takes 10 seconds) and when i call my function I want to use a JProgressBar to see the progress, but the button and the program is block, i need to to make in other thread? and how can I do it? an example of my code:

```
btnEjecutar.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
        //the function
        generarDocumento(nombre);
            }
```

Comment: Take a look at this doc: http://stackoverflow.com/a/782309/32090

Comment: This is a rather generic question and has nothing to do with Apache POI in particular. Take a look at Oracle's [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html) - it covers your use-case quite well.

Comment: Take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details about the problem and [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for a possible solution

Comment: And [for example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23125642/swingworker-in-another-swingworkers-done-method/23126410#23126410), [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20739488/swingworker-in-multithreaded-jframes/20739571#20739571), [exampe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24835638/issues-with-swingworker-and-jprogressbar/24835935#24835935), [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15199091/progress-bar-java/15199220#15199220), [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22031086/jprogressbar-not-working-properly/22031159#22031159) ...

Comment: Avoid using `MouseListener` with buttons, instead use an `ActionListener`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use an invokeLater, like the example bellow:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        generarDocumento(nombre);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Event listeners are executed in the UI thread. If an event listener takes a long time, the UI will stop working/lock up/block/hang.

My guess is that the method `generarDocumento()` takes a long time. If you want the UI to continue working, you must run it in a worker thread. The Java documentation contains several examples how to do that: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html

The [last example in the tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/bound.html) contains demo code how to update a progress bar: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/ProgressBarDemoProject/src/components/ProgressBarDemo.java

Note: The linked content is copyrighted; therefore I can't copy it here.

Comment: Thanks! i've got it, but now how can i put a jprogressbar in a new window?

Comment: @marcss: use `setProgress()`, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4637725/230513).